# Ruby - get the file being executed

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a reference to the script passed to the ruby interpreter. For example, if I'm running `ruby foo.rb` I want to get a reference to the `foo.rb` file.

I think in Python this would be accessible through `sys.argv[0]`. One could call `__FILE__` however this is not solution I'm looking for, since `__FILE__` yields the file inside which the currently execute code lies in.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found `$0` is the name of the file used to start the program. Easy enough.

Answer (score 55):

Use methods in the File class to manipulate **FILE**

Inside test.rb, I have

```
puts __FILE__
puts File.dirname(__FILE__)
puts File.basename(__FILE__)
```

When you run,

```
ruby a/b/test.rb
```

You get

```
a/b/test.rb
a/b
test.rb
```

Comment: will not work http://softwareapprenticeship.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/0-in-ruby-is-worth-more-than-youd-think/

Comment: As said _ _ FILE _ _ gets the current file of the executing script. That is it for code in test.rb it will always return test.rb, for code in something_else.rb it will always return something_else.rb. My question was to return the script initially run by ruby interpreter.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. When running files from `irb`, I do not want `$0` to tell me that the program name is `irb`, but I want to know which script file is being executed.

Answer (score 6):

Let me add an official link to `$0` for the readers.
It is one of global variables offered by Ruby itself.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html

> Contains the name of the script being executed. May be assignable.